# Visual Basic Threads - Beginner informations

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, vb.net-2010

I'm having a simple beginner question about Threads in Visual Basic (2010):
If I start a sub as a new thread and in this sub, an other sub is called.

Is this one also running inside this additional thread?

```
private sub output (...
  output1
  outout2
  ...
end sub

private sub IsGonnaBeAnExtraThread(..
  ...
  output(..)
  ...
end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute sub1 in a threadA and if sub1 calls sub2, then sub2 and all  procedures called by sub2 will be executed in thread A.